# How to update the URL of an Android TWA?

Tags: java, android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

So Our PWA already handles push notifications that tell it to go to a new URL.  I got the TWA up and running and the push notifications are working except they don't do anything, they just open the app.
I can get the data in the notification using

```
Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
```

What I can't find is how do I tell the TWA to go to the new URL after it's already started? Can you not update the URL of a TWA?

Comment: Are you using web push notifications or native push? Can you provide more details?

Comment: We're using Firebase messaging.  The notification seems to work properly.  Clicking on it opens the app properly, but it just opens to the home page.  The notification has a url in it that the app is supposed to open but I can't tell the TWA to go to it.

Comment: Firebase has a native Android API and a Web API. The solution is different depending on what's being used. Can you confirm which one?

Comment: Sorry I didn't set up the firebase project, I believe for the PWA we're just using web push notifications.

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this eventually? We're considering just using postMessage in order to communicate between the Android wrapper and the web code inside of it, but would like to know if updating the URL is possible without basically relaunching the entire Android activity and spawning a new activity with the updated URL.